# Binning Pandas Dataframe by custom and variable length datetime ranges

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, binning

I am trying to use pd.cut to bin rows detailing results for test conducted over variable lengths of time. The purpose of the bins is to ultimately add a new column where I can define which test each row of test results belongs to based on whether the timestamp recorded for that test result falls within a defined time range for that test.

The data in df looks like the following

```
Index  DeviceID    QuantResult1    QuantResult2  Timestamp
  0    15D         7903            387403        2017-10-14 00:28:00
  1    15D         3429734         786           2017-10-14 00:29:10
  2    15D         2320923         546           2017-10-14 00:31:15
  3    15D         232             435869        2017-10-14 00:50:05
  4    15D         34032984        12            2017-10-14 01:10:07
```

Thus far I tried creating separate datetime ranges for each separate test such that

```
test_1 = pd.date_range(start = '2017-10-14 00:20:00', end = '2017-10-14 00:33:15', freq = 'S')
test_2 = pd.date(pd.date_range(start = '2017-10-14 00:49:15', end = '2017-10-14 01:15:15', freq = 'S')
```

etc.

Then I created a list of the date_ranges across all the tests

```
 test_list = [test_1,test_2]
```

Then I tried using pd.cut

```
 df = pd.cut(df['Timestamp'],bins = test_list, labels = ['Test_1','Test_2'])
```

However I get the following error:

```
TypeError: <class 'int'> type object 0.
```

Ultimately I want the data to look like this

```
    Index  DeviceID    QuantResult1    QuantResult2  Timestamp         Test
  0    15D         7903            387403        2017-10-14 00:28:00  Test_1 
  1    15D         3429734         786           2017-10-14 00:29:10  Test_1
  2    15D         2320923         546           2017-10-14 00:31:15  Test_1  
  3    15D         232             435869        2017-10-14 00:50:05  Test_2
  4    15D         34032984        12            2017-10-14 01:10:07  Test_2
```

Can you tell me what the source of the error is?

I already tried mapping the test_list as integers and comparing to the df following converting the df['Timestamp'] column to np.int64 as shown below.

```
test_list_int64 = list(map(np.int64,test_list))
df = pd.cut(df['Timestamp'].astype(np.int64),bins = test_list_int64)
```

But that effort gave the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1320,) (87480,)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the start and end times of each period, then you really don't need to create a range. You can just use logic with the datetime objects. Should be easy to generalize to more and more tests if you have that.

```
import pandas as pd

start_t1 = pd.to_datetime('2017-10-14 00:20:00')
stop_t1 = pd.to_datetime('2017-10-14 00:33:15')
start_t2 = pd.to_datetime('2017-10-14 00:49:15')
stop_t2 = pd.to_datetime('2017-10-14 01:15:15')

df.loc[(df.Timestamp > start_t1) & (df.Timestamp < stop_t1), 'Test'] = 'Test_1'
df.loc[(df.Timestamp > start_t2) & (df.Timestamp < stop_t2), 'Test'] = 'Test_2'

  DeviceID  Quant Result2  QuantResult1           Timestamp    Test
0      15D         387403          7903 2017-10-14 00:28:00  Test_1
1      15D            786       3429734 2017-10-14 00:29:10  Test_1
2      15D            546       2320923 2017-10-14 00:31:15  Test_1
3      15D         435869           232 2017-10-14 00:50:05  Test_2
4      15D             12      34032984 2017-10-14 01:10:07  Test_2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boundary = pd.to_datetime('2017-10-14 00:30:00')
```

now use `np.where`

```
test['Test'] = np.where(test['TimeStamp']< boundary, 'test_1', np.where(test['TimeStamp'], 'test_2', None))
```

output:

```
    Index  DeviceID    QuantResult1    QuantResult2              TimeStamp           Test
    0   15D     7903       387403   2017-10-14 00:28:00     2017-10-14 00:28:00     test_1
    1   15D     3429734     786     2017-10-14 00:29:10     2017-10-14 00:29:10     test_1
    2   15D     2320923     546     2017-10-14 00:31:15     2017-10-14 00:31:15     test_2
    3   15D     232         435869  2017-10-14 00:50:05     2017-10-14 00:50:05     test_2
    4   15D     34032984    12      2017-10-14 01:10:07     2017-10-14 01:10:07     test_2
```